# Is it possible to show the actual exact count of likes in the layout style "box count" and not have the numbers rounded?

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like, rounding

Is it possible to show the actual exact count of likes in the layout style "box count" for example 1019 not the rounded 1K in the like button on my homepage?

I do not want to use the standard layout style.  I want to use the box count.

Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 0):

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://url.to/get/likes

you can get it with PHP & put it to page

so for example

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents("http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.stackoverflow.com");
$id_likes = json_decode($data);
$likes = $id_likes->shares;
echo $likes;
?>
```

[working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/facebook-likes-8d1c.php)

Comment: Thanks,  I see how this works...

Can you tell me where I can insert this to get the number to show up in the grey box area??
http://oi53.tinypic.com/ofn3o9.jpg